# Find connected components in javascript 2d matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays

My array maybe looks like this:

```
var array = [
    [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

I'd like to find all connected components in this 2d matrix like the 'E'-character in the middle, the (lets call it SQUARE) in the left corner above and the other "square" in the right bottom and mark them all with different numbers to get a result like this:

```
var result = [
        [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    ]
```

My code that works absolutely well looks like this:

```js
var array = [
        [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
      ]
      
      
      
      

function find_connected_components(array) {
 var default_value=1;
 function test_connection(array, i, j, value) {
     if (array[i] && array[i][j] === -1) {
         array[i][j] = value;
         test_connection(array, i + 1, j, value);
         test_connection(array, i, j + 1, value);
         return true;
     }
 }
 array.forEach(function (a) {
     a.forEach(function (b, i, bb) {bb[i] = -b;});
 });
 array.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
     a.forEach(function (b, j, bb) {test_connection(aa, i, j, default_value) && default_value++;});
 })
 console.log(array.map(a => [a.join('')]).map(a => [a.join('')]))
}


find_connected_components(array)
```

But- now my error appears until I rotate my array from above. SO that it looks like this:

```
var error_array = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],  
]
```

The result for the **error_array** above is completely wrong & I have no clue how to fix this.

PS: I haven't edited a ERROR-array code snippet because my question would be to long. Soo please try the error_array for your own.

And I hope somebody can explain how to fix my code:)

> **Edit** 1 : This is the output for the error_array

[image]

Thanks a million in advance!

Greetings jonas

Comment: 1 question out of pure curiosity, what are you using this code for ?

Comment: trees it as adjacency matrix and apply dfs to find connected components

Comment: It's part of a search algorithm to find geometric figures in a 2d matrix @Taurus

Comment: @Jonas0000 Thanks for answering, I was actually asking what its non-technical use would be, are you trying to find geometric figures in matrices for some other practical purpose or is finding geometric figures in 2d matrices the end ? If that's not too much asking :)

Comment: @Taurus what do you mean with 'non-technical use'? I do not understand your question... EDIT: Ok, I saw you've edited your question. It's part of an OCR Reader / Scanner for specific codes we've created on our own.

Comment: Like, does your program have a UI ? Is it going to be used by non-technical people ? Or are you just trying to learn something from this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem: your `test_connection` is kind of like a [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), but it only moves to right and down. You need to modify your function to fill up and to the left as well.

It works for the first case pretty well because the "E" shape can be filled correctly when only moving right and down from the top-left point. But when the "E" is flipped (your second case, the recursive call no longer reaches the horizontal bars of the "E".

Comment: Ok sound legit.. But how to edit the `test_connection` function to move in all directions? Absolutely no clue how to code this!

Comment: Call `test_connection` recursively two more times, but moving in the up and left directions (i.e. `test_connection(array, i - 1, j, value);`). You'll want to ensure that you don't process the same square twice, or else you'll end up in an infinite loop. You'll also need to check your indices to make sure they don't go out of bounds for the array.

Comment: Ok I think I got what you mean with calling `test_connection`  two more times. So at least I will edit this: `test_connection(array, i - 1, j, value); test_connection(array, i, j - 1, value);` But how to check my indices when I just get through every element of my array? Wouldn't it be irrelevant? Thanks.

Comment: I think the line `array[i] && array[i][j] === -1` is already checking to make sure you're within the bounds, so you're probably good. I was mainly giving general advice when implementing a flood fill :).

Answer (score 0):

First, change the value of `1` to `-1`, because you need to use `1` as flag.

Then you could iterate the elements and perform a check and if it has the flag `-1`, then change it to the actual value. Proceed with the element of the right and bottom.

If an element was found, increment value.

```js
function test(array, i, j, value) {
    if (array[i] && array[i][j] === -1) {
        array[i][j] = value;
        test(array, i -1, j, value);
        test(array, i + 1, j, value);
        test(array, i, j - 1, value);
        test(array, i, j + 1, value);
        return true;
    }
}

var data = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
    value = 1;

data.forEach(function (a) {
    a.forEach(function (b, i, bb) {
        bb[i] = -b;
    });
});

data.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    a.forEach(function (b, j, bb) {
        test(aa, i, j, value) && value++;
    });
});

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = data.map(function (a) { return a.join(' '); }).join('\n');
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```